# Is next used as fullstack scalable with kubernetes deployment?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, next.js

I am trying to setup a frontend with nextjs and spring boot as backend for one of the internal products of my company. My colleague suggested to look into nextjs as for backend as well.

SSO will be used as authentication for the product and ingress will be used as load balancer between kubernetes nodes (Atleast 3 nodes), with mysql as database with galera cluster (2 nodes atleast for database).

Will this setup work if I use nextjs as a fullstack framework?

Currently have implemented frontend side of it and tried to host it. It was successful.

Nextjs version: 14.0.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes**, technically, you can use **Next.js** alongside **SSO** as a full-stack application on **Kubernetes**. In fact, there are companies like `Netflix`, `Twitch`, `Vercel` etc. who have successfully productionized full-stack applications based on `nextjs`

However, the feasibility and ideal approach depend heavily on your specific application architecture and expected load.

`SSO` and `Kubernetes` should be the least of your worries. but the word `scalable` may apply differently based on the context. it has a direct relation to the architecture, load, and requirements of your app.

While Next.js, SSO, and Kubernetes can work together, there's no one-size-fits-all solution. Carefully evaluate your application's architecture, load requirements, and available resources before choosing the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

Microservices architecture involves breaking down a software application into smaller, independently deployable services. This architecture is preferred for its scalability, flexibility, and ability to use different technologies for different services.

If you implement an authentication service within next.js, this setup will be bad because if your next.js pod goes down, you will lose two services, authentication and front-end service.

If you want to use the next.js for its server-side-rendering benefit for the client, you have to be careful where you make requests. if you are on the server your request URL will be different and it will need extra configuration

Comment: Authentication used will be of Microsoft SSO. Do think it is a good idea to go with serverless implementation with high scalability? Does implementing a server in spring boot for REST APIs help in high scalability?